# Namespaces and Accessing Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question, though I'm not sure what language to use. I'm a little confused about how to access the canvas defined in the main driver module from other modules without using globals. For instance, I have instantiated the canvas in driver.py, but am trying to draw from Level.py. For context, it is eventually going to read a text file and draw a map based on the data it extracts from it for an RPG-ish game. Here is my code:

Driver.py:

```
import tkinter
import Level


HEIGHT = 1024
WIDTH = 800
TILE_SIZE = 32
VERTICAL_TILES = HEIGHT//TILE_SIZE
HORIZONTAL_TILES = WIDTH//TILE_SIZE

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("RPG Land")
window = tkinter.Canvas(root,width= WIDTH, height=HEIGHT )


lev = Level.LevelMgr()
lev.loadLevel()
lev.drawLevel()

window.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Annnd Level.py:

```
import tkinter
from driver import window

class LevelMgr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.levelData = []
        self.visibleLevel = []
        self.tileColors = {
                            0 : 'empty',
                            1 : 'wall',
                            2 : 'bush' }

    def loadLevel(self):
        fyle = open('levels/level1','r')
        count = 0
        for lyne in fyle:
            self.levelData.append(lyne)
            count += 1


    def drawLevel(self):
        currentY = 0
        currentX = 0
        for col in self.levelData:
            currentY += 32
            for t in col:
                window.create_rectangle(currentX, currentY, 32, 32, fill="blue")
                currentX += 32
```

Any advice on how to structure the program better would be also appreciated. When accessing other namespaces, what is the proper way to do so? Do I need to have "import Level" on driver.py, as well as "import driver" in Level.py? I'm a little confused as to the fundamental structure of such a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LevelMgr` depends on window, so name it explicitly in `__init__`:

```
class LevelMgr:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
    def drawLevel(self):
        ...
            for t in col:
                self.window.create_rectangle(currentX, currentY, 32, 32, fill="blue")
```

Remove the import statement:

```
from driver import window
```

Then, in Driver.py:

```
lev = Level.LevelMgr(window)
```

---

Another possibility is to simply define `window` in Level.py instead of `Driver.py`.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense. So I must explicitly pass a reference to window in order to access it? Just for good measure, why wouldn't it work with just the import statement? Why is that not the same as passing a reference of window to the Level module?

Comment: The way you had it written probably would work, but it uses a circular import: Driver imports Level, and Level imports Driver. It makes you wonder why they both just aren't in the same file. If you *do* want them in separate files, then it is best to break the circular import. Let one, the master (`Driver`), import the helper modules (`Level`). Ideally, the `LevelMgr` should be reusable and self-contained. Whatever it needs from the outside world should be passed explicitly as an argument to `__init__`. That way, people understand what it takes to use `LevelMgr`.